# My node is down because of a bad stellar-core.cfg configuration in stellar network

Tags: json, configuration, blockchain, vps, stellar

I have created a validator node in the Stellar network.
But it is being down automatically because of bad configuration.
What do I have to do or change?

My VPS size is 250GB & CPU is 16GB.

```
INVARIANT_CHECKS=[".*"]

TARGET_PEER_CONNECTIONS=8
MAX_PENDING_CONNECTIONS=5000
PEER_AUTHENTICATION_TIMEOUT=5
PEER_TIMEOUT=30
PREFERRED_PEERS=[]
PREFERRED_PEER_KEYS=[]
PREFERRED_PEERS_ONLY=false
MINIMUM_IDLE_PERCENT=0

FAILURE_SAFETY=1
UNSAFE_QUORUM=false

CATCHUP_COMPLETE=false
CATCHUP_RECENT=60480
MAX_CONCURRENT_SUBPROCESSES=10

RUN_STANDALONE=false
MANUAL_CLOSE=false
ARTIFICIALLY_GENERATE_LOAD_FOR_TESTING=false
ARTIFICIALLY_ACCELERATE_TIME_FOR_TESTING=false
ALLOW_LOCALHOST_FOR_TESTING=false
```

Comment: I have an issue too, when I run the node, it is working well but it is down after 10~15days

Comment: Yes, it is correct, I am too.